# Log in password check HTML JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, validation, authentication, passwords

I've been trying to get my password to validate for the following conditions:

- If password / username is less than 5 characters, error box will appear
- If password / username / both is not entered, error box will appear
- If password is incorrect, error box will appear
- If password is correct, box will appear to indicate successful login

Here is my javascript coding:

```
 <script> function validateForm()
 {
 var x=document.forms["Login"]["user"].value;
 var y=document.forms["Login"]["pass"].value;
 if (x==null || x=="")
   {
   alert("Error: Username and password must be entered ");
   return false;
   }
 if(x.length<5){
    alert("Your username must be at least \n5 characters long. \n Please try again.");
    return false;
    }
if (y==null || y=="")
   {
   alert("Error: Username and password must be entered");
   return false;
   }
if(y.length<5){
    alert("Your username must be at least\n5 characters long.\n Please try again.");
    //Login.txtpass.value = "";
    //Login.txtpass.focus();
    return false;
 }
else{
alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
return false;

}

alert("You entered a valid password: " + Login.pass.value);
return true;

 }
 </script>
```

At the minute all 3 of the above successfully happen but now there cannot be a successful login that existed before i created the script. How would i get the login to do this via javascript?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you bother going through all that effort on the client side when a user can easily disable all your hard work by opening up their console? I would recommend doing some server-side validation on this one.

Comment: Oh and regarding your validation rules; a user can not set their password to `00000000000`? Because `(00000000000 == "") = true`

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen - Of course you need to do server-side validation, but that does not mean that client-side checks are useless. Validating the basic through JavaScript allows you to provide the user with quick feedback that doesn't require a round-trip to the server.

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir I'm sorry if I wasn't clear about that. I didn't mean to say that client-side validation is useless. On the contrary! I completely agree with you regarding the user feedback. I do quite some client-side validation myself in my open source form library [ValidForm Builder](http://validformbuilder.org).

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen: An input field's value is always a string, and so `"0000" == ""` will evaluate to false, because a numeric string != an empty string

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem true. But my question is, should one treat numeric input as a string? If I submit 0000000000 as a password, it is in fact a number; not a string. That Javascript interprets this value as a string doesn't mean it is actually a string, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to clarify. :) Also, passwords are strings. I can't imagine why you'd want to convert it to a number unless you were making a pin, and even then you'd want leading zeros to be included.

Answer (score 1):

You always return before you go to the last alert.

```
if(y.length<5){
    // something
    return false;
}
else{
    // something
    return false;
}
// you can't go there !
```

The logic you try to implement isn't clear but you probably should remove the last block starting with `else{`.

Comment: thats correct, it does work without the last else but that kind of defeats the purpose.